# GUI performance degrade when i am making calls more than 20

Tags: android, performance, user-interface

I am newbie to android. In my tablet, if I make calls more 20, performance degrade. GUI response is very slow. why does the gui performance degrade?

I have a trace file. I didn't find the root cause. There is no memory problem.

Please help me out

Logcat messages:

Comment: What does "making calls more than 20" mean?

Comment: i mean that 20 calls in conference

Answer (score 1):

You should use AsyncTasks for longer processes to keep the UI up and running smooth!